# R: Write function to create dataframe and then use this dataframe for further manipulation

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I wrote a function that returns a dataframe as output.
How can I get this dataframe in the global environment after performing the function?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: return the `data.frame` at the end of your function?

Comment: Refer to the object as the last statement of the function or use `return()` as @Base_R_Best_R refers to in the first comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot. ```return()``` did the job